# where is the RESOURCES folder in the new xCode4.2

Tags: iphone, resources, icons, xcode4.2, navigator

I can't seem to find the Resources folder in the new xCode4.2 project navigator
where do i put the image resources for my app icon in this new xCode4.2?

Here is a screenshot: 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like many samples from Apple now use the Supporting Files folder instead.  You can go ahead and create your own Resources folder, or go ahead and use Apple's Supporting Files folder.

Comment: but for the icon file of the iPhone app, do we not need to keep the icon in the resources folder? i mean that's the defined place from where iPhone app looks for media resources, right?

Comment: If you use "Show Package Contents" on one of the apps you build, you will see that it does not have a Resources folder.  All the items that were in your Resources folder in the Xcode project are at the top level of your app bundle.  If you had sub folders in the Resources folder, then those folders would be in the app bundle.  In other words, it doesn't make a difference whether they are in the Resources or the Supporting files folder, as long as the build rule is still there, taking those files and putting them in the app bundle.