# how to create plist file in xcode 4.3.2

Tags: iphone, ios, plist

I am trying to create my own plist file to be used in my application, I am using apple [documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW5) as refrence for doing this.

However, I have read that if you create your own plist you need to place it in the resource folder in your applications build. The issue with that is that I have no resources folder in my build... so I am woundering what should I do?.. I have read this guys answere [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507997/where-is-the-resources-folder-in-the-new-xcode4-2), he says its fine to just place the plist file in the supporting Files folder.. is this okay to do in regards to allowing the plist to be read and written too?

Comment: You can't write to the application bundle once it is installed on a device. You need to copy it into the apps sandbox once the app is installed and then you can read and write from there. In terms of the xcode project you can put the file pretty much anywhere you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put that plist file anywhere you want.
The important thing will be copying it into the bundle. So to be sure for that check 
`project settings>build phases>copy bundle resources`

You can open project settings by left-clicking on your project in the project navigator.

Comment: cool thanks for the quick reply.. Okay I understand now.. I had ready about it needing to be in the bundle but wasn't 100% on what was or was not included in that..

Answer (score 5):

To read and write to plist the best practice is to copy it to document root if you want to access it through bundle you don't have write permission. I have provided a snap shot of the code here and how you can accomplish this.

```
NSError *err;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
//getting the path to document directory for the file
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFile.plist"];

//checking to see of the file already exist
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path])
{
    //if doesnt exist get the the file path from bindle
    NSString *correctPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourFile.plist"];
    //copy the file from bundle to document dir
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:correctPath toPath:path error:&err];      
}
```

Comment: okay thanks, I think  Ifound a tutorial earlier thats very similar to this. I am thinking about having a controller class that will do all the plist stuff for me, so when I need to write something to it I can call the class method I need that dose that. etc.. do you think thats a good idea?

Comment: Yes, That's a good practice and it will take care of code repetition, if you need help with this i can show you a class that i have created to read and write to plist?

Comment: Would you believe I have managed to follow the tutorial and I have everything up and runinng really well.. however I am now trying to add a dictionary to the root dictionary of the plist.. and am not sure how to go about setting up the values etc.. I have a question going here that you might be able to help me with.. :P
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003856/how-to-add-values-to-a-dictionary-inside-a-dictionary-of-a-property-list